# How to create BreadCrumbs in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to create BreadCrumbs in JSF pages. The problem is that I have several paths that I need to remember. I need to implement some kind of memory in which I can remember the opened pages and the page path. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I found this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/breadCrumb.jsf but the path is hard coded.

Comment: @user1285928 and what stops you from replacing that behavior with an `<ui:repeat>` that shows the values of a `@SessionScoped` queue?

Comment: Ok, check [this code](https://bitbucket.org/ElderMael/jgtjo/src/33c816b4e03e/schedule-parent/schedule-web/src/main/java/mx/gob/jgtjo/apps/schedule/web/utils/BreadCrumbMenuItemFactory.java?at=master), basically is a properties file that maps sections of RESTful URIs to menu items, if you like it I can post it as a answer.

Comment: [Here](https://bitbucket.org/ElderMael/jgtjo/src/33c816b4e03e/schedule-parent/schedule-web/src/main/resources/mx/gob/jgtjo/apps/schedule/web/breadcrumb.properties?at=master) is the sample properties file

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  I have JSF pages with AJAX. I don't think that `@SessionScoped` in AJAX pages is a good idea.

Comment: @mael let me see your proposal.

Comment: @user1285928 why you think that? Is just theory based or for a previous bad experience with it?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Yes - bad experience. If you want you can propose a working example.